# How to check if /proc/ is mounted

Tags: linux, mount, proc

How can I check if /proc/ is mounted?

- Using /etc/mtab is discouraged as it
  might be inconsistent.
- Using /proc/mounts is also not an
  option as might not exist if /proc/
  is not mounted (although checking for
  its existence may be a way to do this
  check.

What is the best way to do this check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run the `mount` without any arguments to get a list of current mounts. The `/etc/mtab` file should have similar data, but like you said it is possible for this to be inconsistent with what is actually mounted in the event that the `/etc` file system is messed up, not writable, or another program has messed with it. You can get specific information about the proc mounts by asking `mount` to list all mounts of type `proc` like this:

```
mount -l -t proc
```

**Edit:** It looks like you can use `stat` to compare the device of the `/proc` folder to the device of `/` to tell at least if SOMETHING is mounted there other than the root file system:

```
[[ $(stat -c %d%D /proc) != $(stat -c %d%D /) ]] && echo "Something is mounted at /proc"
```

Comment: This is indeed one way to do it. The risk here is the running the mount command might get stuck on various problematic mounts like NFS/CIFS shares which are disconnected.

Comment: @freddie: Does it actually get stuck if you ask it to list mounts of type proc like I showed? I don't have a case I can test right now, but if it's decently implemented I don't see why it would hang on scanning the status of nfs mounts if asked to list only proc mounts. Note that I did NOT recommend running `mount | grep proc` for just that reason.

Comment: I will need to test it, but I agree, if it's implemented properly, mount -l should not get stuck and in that case this is a good solution. Although, mount -l returns return code 0 if it finds a mount point (or more) or if it doesn't find it. So the check is further complicated by using mount -l -t proc |wc -l and checking how many filesystems are returned :(

Comment: @freddie: see my edit for another solution. Also you could use a string test on the mount without running wc: `[[ -n $(mount -l -t proc) ]]`

Answer (score 3):

Test for the existence of `/proc/mounts`. Running `mount` is no good because if `/proc` isn't mounted, it will return potentially obsolete data from `/etc`.

In theory there might be something else at `/proc`. But this is extremely unlikely in practice: if `/proc/mounts` exists and `/proc` isn't the `proc` filesystem, you can't trust anything about your environment anyway. If you're really worried, you can check that the filesystem type is `proc`: `df -PT /proc | awk 'NR==2 && $2=="proc" {print 1}'` (requires the Linux utilities `df`, there's no corresponding option in Busybox). Conversely, in theory, there could be a proc filesystem mounted in a different place; there's no easy way to find this with shell commands (`df` reads `/proc/mounts` to enumerate filesystems). In practice, just check for `/proc/mounts`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a (more or less) guarantee that the filesystem on /proc is in fact proc instead of some other filesystem or a directory structure made to look like it, you can call [`statfs()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs) and check the type, `0x9fa0` is the value for proc.

Answer (score 1):

There is tool called `mountpoint` avaiable on many linux installations.
The exitcode is 0 if the first argument is a mountpoint.