# How to get the complete and exact list of mounted filesystems in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I usually use `mount` to check which filesystems are mounted. I also know there is some connection between `mount` and `/etc/mtab` but I'm not sure about the details. After reading [How to check if /proc/ is mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16154/how-to-check-if-proc-is-mounted) I get more confused.

My question is: How to get the most precise list of mounted filesystems? Should I just use `mount`, or read the contents of `/etc/mtab`, or contents of `/proc/mounts`? What would give the most trustworthy result?

Comment: You should also read the accepted answer to this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12040/what-mount-points-exist-on-a-typical-linux-system

Comment: I can't help linking to [What is /etc/mtab in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/514095/259023) because it covers non-Linux details that none of the answers here give.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The definitive list of mounted filesystems is in `/proc/mounts`.

If you have any form of containers on your system, `/proc/mounts` only lists the filesystems that are in your present container. For example, in a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot), `/proc/mounts` lists only the filesystems whose mount point is within the chroot. ([There are ways to escape the chroot, mind.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot/14346#14346))

There's also a list of mounted filesystems in `/etc/mtab`. This list is maintained by the `mount` and `umount` commands. That means that if you don't use these commands (which is pretty rare), your action (mount or unmount) won't be recorded. In practice, it's mostly in a chroot that you'll find `/etc/mtab` files that differ wildly from the state of the system. Also, mounts performed in the chroot will be reflected in the chroot's `/etc/mtab` but not in the main `/etc/mtab`. Actions performed while `/etc/mtab` is on a read-only filesystem are also not recorded there.

The reason why you'd sometimes want to consult `/etc/mtab` in preference to or in addition to `/proc/mounts` is that because it has access to the mount command line, it's sometimes able to present information in a way that's easier to understand; for example you see mount options as requested (whereas `/proc/mounts` lists the `mount` and kernel defaults as well), and bind mounts appear as such in `/etc/mtab`.

Comment: What's the point of `mount` maintaining `/etc/mtab` if it can't be relied upon? Wouldn't it be better if `mount` presented information from `/proc/mounts` instead?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost `/etc/mtab` can record information that the kernel doesn't track, such as the options originally requested, and bind mounts appearing as such instead of appearing as duplicate entries for devices. Nonetheless many distributions are moving towards making `/etc/mtab` a symlink to `/proc/mounts`.

Comment: *Nonetheless many distributions are moving towards making `/etc/mtab` a symlink to `/proc/mounts`.* Good to hear – adding this information to answer would make it even better. Do you think tracking requested options by the kernel would be feasible and beneficial?

Comment: Note that you'll need to un-escape the contents of /proc/mounts.  As described on the getmntent(3) page, space (\040), tab (\011), newline (\012) and backslash (\134) need to be handled specially.  Especially if user mounts are enabled, you'll need to be very careful when working with these paths.

Comment: Hi, I see a mount point in the list, although it is old line and there is not real mount there, how can it be ?

Comment: Please see also other answer for using command `findmnt` which is the preferred way since 2010 and probable the only safe way in near future when mount namespaces will be common.

Answer (score 154):

[As of v. 2.18 (July 2010)](http://karelzak.blogspot.com/2010/07/findmnt8.html) `util-linux` includes a tool that allows you to display a list of currently mounted file systems:

```
findmnt
```

You can switch from the default tree view to list view with `-l`, define output columns with `-o` (similar to `lsblk`), filter results based on filesystem type with `-t` etc...

```
findmnt -lo source,target,fstype,label,options,used -t ext4
```

```
SOURCE    TARGET      FSTYPE LABEL OPTIONS                           USED
/dev/sda1 /           ext4   ARCH  rw,noatime,discard,data=ordered  17.6G
/dev/sdb2 /media/DATA ext4   DATA  rw,noatime,discard,data=ordered    44M
```

As of [version 2.27](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/Documentation/releases/v2.27-ReleaseNotes) there's also support for `JSON` output via `-J` or `--json` switch:

```
findmnt -Jo source,target,label,uuid -t ext4
```

```
{
   "filesystems": [
      {
         "source": "/dev/nvme0n1p5",
         "target": "/",
         "label": "ARCH",
         "uuid": "f21a53194-b02a-4e92-ad96-fdf9b8bc1db9",
         "children": [
            {
               "source": "/dev/nvme0n1p6",
               "target": "/run/media/data",
               "label": "DATA",
               "uuid": "321e288a-e67c-4b68-8d0b-89720210921f"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

For more details read the `man` page (and `findmnt --help` to get the list of available columns).

Comment: This answer provides the most comprehensive list, including the most obscure mounts like /sys/fs/bpf, /sys/fs/cgroup, /sys/firmware/efi/efivars etc. A lot to wade through, but grep is your friend.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves the problem when you just wish to know the target in a single list, this way I can use it in a script to invoke the right device, just by greping a part of the target's name.

Comment: Most importantly it has a `--json` for easy python parsing.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. It's already structured and it even has `json` support. Finally, we can get rid of the mess `mount` produces! This command should be more popular and become the new default. The original `mount` is an utter & useless joke compared to this!

Comment: very good answer! in the man pages there is also the `avail` option which I find really useful, showing also how much space left on the volume: `findmnt -lo source,target,fstype,label,options,used,avail -t ext4`

Answer (score 60):

Maybe because it has been 5 years since this question was answered things have changed. The `cat /proc/mounts` creates a lot of info you do not care about. Today, IMHO, I find this to be the ultimate solution.

```
df -h --output=source,target
```

when you read the man pages there are all kinds of options you can do but this is what you what. For example to clean up the results even more you can exclude file types of "tmpfs" with this command:

```
df -hx tmpfs --output=source,target
```

`df` works on the filesystem level and not the file level.

The commands above will include network mounts as well.

To see a little more information use this:

```
df -hT
```

**NOTE** With slow mounted network connections this can take several minutes!

If you don't have or care about mounted network connections (and you have root permissions) than this is even better:

```
sudo lsblk -f
```

Comment: You don't have to be root but some of the fields/columns (such as Label) will have null data, which might still be okay in that the questions wants to know what filesystems are mounted.

Comment: Ubuntu. However I just discovered "findmnt" that doesn't use root and it lists network mounted filesystems. I was thinking of editing my answer to include that knowledge.

Comment: :-) I tired to give your answer a vote but can't until I have a rep of 15+

Comment: Btw, if you're trying to use `--output` with something like Ubuntu 12 which doesn't accept those options, check out don_crissti's `findmnt` answer below which does.

Comment: `findmnt` seems to need higher capabilities (tested with root; root has all capabilities) to display labels.

Comment: df does not show bind mounted folders, findmnt do show them

Answer (score 24):

Most of the time, `mount` is the most convenient method. For a complete and exact list of currently mounted filesystems, you should read the contents of `/proc/mounts` (e.g., with `cat /proc/mounts`).

For example, if mounting `/` readwrite failed and it was then mounted readonly as a fallback, `/etc/mtab` (which the `mount` command reads from to tell you what's mounted, and writes to--if it can--when it changes what is mounted) would not be updated to reflect that `/` (which contains `/etc/mtab`) is currently mounted readonly. In this situation, running `mount` would typically tell you (incorrectly) that `/` was mounted readwrite.

Under normal conditions (i.e., when the filesystem that contains it can be written to), `/etc/mtab` contains a list of currently mounted filesystems. This is not to be confused with `/etc/fstab`, which contains a list of filesystems that are supposed to get mounted automatically when the system starts up.

Of course, if the `/proc` virtual filesystem is itself not mounted, then you cannot read any of the virtual files in it, which would include `/proc/mounts`. This very rarely is the case. In this situation, `mount` is probably your best option for seeing what's mounted.

Answer (score 4):

If the mounted source for some reason is no longer accessible (in my case my domain password expired), the mount point directory is empty and (at least for me) the mount no longer shows up in `/proc/mount`.

I desperately searched for any such mounts since I suspected there was some mount that frequently tried to access my domain account with old credentials (every few seconds) and thereby frequently locked the account. That´s why I found this question in the first place. But `/proc/mounts` was not the solution for me.

I knew I had probably done some mounting from an Ubuntu server with a command like the below, but was unsure of what `mount_point_dir` I could have used, since none of my regular mount_points seemed to be mounted.

```
$ mount.cifs <remotetarget> <mount_point_dir>
```

I finally found a verification that there actually existed some mounting with authorization problems from the syslog in `/var/log/syslog`. I saw a lot of lines in this log with the following statements:

```
CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response
Status code returned 0xc0000234 STATUS_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT
```

That confirmed my suspicions and I could then get further confirmation from looking at the Stats and DebugData under the `/proc/fs/cifs` folder.

See further information [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cifs/usage.html#misc-proc-fs-cifs-flags-and-debug-info).

Although I never actually saw the information about the target `mount_point_dir`, only the mounted source, this was enough for me to solve my issue, since this motivated me to do a reboot of the server, after which the mounts were gone and also the account locking problem.