# What do first column in /proc/mounts really mean in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, devices

Run `cat /proc/mounts` and I get this (simplified):

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 / ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
io /etc/blkio cgroup rw,relatime,blkio 0 0
...
```

About the content, [document from Red Hat](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific5/docs/rhel/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-mounts.html) says that:

> The first column specifies the device that is mounted,  the second column reveals the mount point, and the third column tells the file system type...

I don't think that `rootfs` is a device, I'm trying to find this device in `udev(/dev)` but I can't get it. So I don't know which device is mounted in `/` (*You may say that I can use `mount` to get this information, but what if `rootfs` here is mounted not by `mount` command*).

Another example is on VMware ESX 3.x server, you cannot find any "vmfs" entry listed in `mount`'s result, but by `cat /proc/mounts`, I get `/vmfs /vmfs vmfs rw 0 0`. As the `rootfs` example, I cannot know which devices are related with the first "/vmfs" here either.

**Question**: Could someone tell me what does the first column of `/proc/mounts` really mean?

PS. Please read "[How to get the complete and exact list of mounted filesystems in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux)" for more information about `/proc/mounts` and `mount`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first column is indeed the device as the documentation you quoted says.  According to [kernel.org documentation](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt), `rootfs` is just a special case of a `ramfs` (in-RAM filesystem) that the kernel uses to make sure something is always mounted on `/`.  It takes 0 or negligibly small space in RAM only and if you look further in `/proc/mounts` you should see the entry for the device containing your real root partition mounted on `/`.

Comment: I see the real device mounted on `/`, it's `/dev/sda1` as I listed in the output of `cat /proc/mounts`. Now I understand `rootfs` is a special case, thanks. Could you explain the situation described in the "vmfs" example?

Comment: The "vmfs" example may be too specific and I'd better to give up finding its answer. Anyway, based on your answer and my understanding, can I say that the [document from Red Hats](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific5/docs/rhel/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-mounts.html) is not so accurate as `rootfs` is not a **device**?

Comment: I think ramfs counts as a mountable device.  The `/` in front of `/vmfs` makes me think it is a file located in `/`.

Comment: Thanks. Here is [a bit more information on ramfs](http://wiki.debian.org/ramfs), it says that _"The older 'ram disk' mechanism created **a synthetic block device** out of an area of ram_".

Answer (score 3):

The first column in `/proc/mounts` is the device name as recorded by the kernel. Most of the time, this is the name that was provided when calling `mount` (see the code of the [`show_vfsmnt` function](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1/fs/namespace.c#L997) in the kernel); there's a way for a filesystem to tweak that name, but only NFS and AFS take advantage of this opportunity.

The name `rootfs` is [built into the kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1/fs/namespace.c#L997); it's used for the root filesystem at boot time. There are also cases where the kernel doesn't get a name and uses `none`.

When you mount a filesystem that's stored on an actual device, the device name is vital: it indicates where that filesystem is. For [“virtual” filesystems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12040/what-mount-points-exist-on-a-typical-linux-system/12086#12086), the device name is often irrelevant, either there's a single possible backing (e.g. `proc`, `sysfs`, `binfmt_misc`) or each filesystem is independent of any backing (`tmpfs`) or mount options indicate where the underlying data is (most [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystems).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `rootfs` but [`proc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux) is a "playground" for processes. It's a virtual file system so it won't show up in `/dev` (I don't think) but it can be mounted.

The actual devices in `/dev` will be displayed in the first column with an absolute path (like you have for `/dev/sda1`).