# Is there a way to show all flags in /proc/mounts?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, proc

Some filesystem flags seem to be hidden in /proc/mounts, depending on whether they are defined as defaults.

Is there a way to show all flags in /proc/mounts, also including the default ones? And if not, is there another command to see all enabled flags for the mounted filesystems?

My background: I have set the data=writeback flag in fstab and also passed it to the kernel in my grub configuration, but it is still not listed in /proc/mounts. Now, how can I find out whether this is because data=writeback is a default (and thus not shown), or because the flag is indeed not set?

Comment: Not sure if this will be directly accessible or not: http://superuser.com/questions/318293/how-to-know-if-noatime-or-relatime-is-default-mount-option-in-kernel

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux

Comment: I think the answer is to check your kernel version and compare with the source (beware that distributions may occasionally change the defaults). Maybe someone's written a tool for this.