# Mounted dir disappears after restart

Tags: rhel, mount

I ran this command on RHEL 6.3:

```
# mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
```

Everything is okay, but after a restart the mounted dir, `/mnt` disappears...
I don't know where is it going.

Answer (score 4):

Mount doesn't permanently mount the file.  To do that, you must edit your `/etc/fstab` file.  `man fstab` will give you all the documentation you need.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you boot up, nothing is mounted yet and each filesystem must be mounted in turn.  The list of filesystems that should be automatically mounted during boot is in `/etc/fstab` so if you want your cdrom to be mounted automatically on each boot, you must add a line for it to that file.

Answer (score 1):

just add this entry to /etc/fstab file :

```
    /dev/cdrom         /mnt/cdrom            iso9660        ro                0   0
```

Answer (score -2):

Steps to mount a disk permanently.
Doing this will mount your disk during boot time.

0. Attach your disk manually once.
1. Goto `/proc/mounts` and `/etc/mtab` and look for your mount entry.
2. Copy the entry that you want to be mounted on boot.
3. Paste it at the end of `/etc/fstab`. `/etc/fstab` Contains entries that are mounted during boot.

You can even manually add your entry in `/etc/fstab`, but copying it from `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/mtab` makes sure that you not make any error or mistake in listing your mount point

more helpful links [link 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux)     [link 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218859/permanently-mount-reboot-currently-stops)