# What is /etc/mtab in Linux?

Tags: linux, fstab

What is `/etc/mtab` in Linux?

Why is it needed and advantages of having it?

Comment: Related: [Is there a command to see where a disk is mounted?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/34718)

Comment: I find it frustrating that `man 5 mtab` is missing.

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24182/117549

Answer (score 67):

```
% file /etc/mtab
/etc/mtab: symbolic link to ../proc/self/mounts
% file /proc/mounts
/proc/mounts: symbolic link to self/mounts
%
```

`/etc/mtab` is a compatibility mechanism.  Decades ago, Unix did not have a system call for reading the existing mount information.  Instead, programs that mounted filesystems were expected to coöperatively and voluntarily maintain a table in `/etc/mtab` of what was mounted where.

For obvious reasons, this was not an ideal mechanism.

Linux gained the notion of a "procfs", and one of the things that it gained was a kernel-maintained version of this table, in the form of a `mounts` pseudo-regular file.  The "system call" to read the mount information out of the kernel became an open-read-close sequence against that file, followed by parsing the result from human-readable to machine-readable form (something that has some subtle catches, as you can see from the bug reports from just over a fortnight ago).

`/etc/mtab` thus has popularly become a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts`, allowing programs that had hardwired that name to keep reading a mount table from that file, which the programs that mounted and unmounted filesystems no longer have to explicitly do anything themselves to keep up to date.  (Some of them still will, though, if `/etc/mtab` turns out to be a writable regular file.  And there are a few corner cases where the normalized information in `mounts` that lacks all non-kernel stuff is not quite what is needed; although they do not outweigh the general problems with `/etc/mtab`.)

Each process can nowadays have its own individual view of what is mounted, and there are as a consequence now individual `mounts` files for each process in the procfs, each process's own table being accessible to it via the `self` symbolic link as `self/mounts`, and `/proc/mounts` is *also* now a compatibility mechanism.  (Interestingly, neither per-process `mounts` nor the format of `mounts` are documented in the current Linux doco, although the similar `mountinfo` pseudo-regular file is.)

SunOS/Solaris has a similar mechanism.  The `/etc/mnttab` file is actually a single-file filesystem, and in addition to reading the table, via an open file descriptor to that file, with the `read()` system call, one can watch for mount point changes with `poll()` and obtain various further pieces of information with `ioctl()`.

In HP-UX, `/etc/mnttab` is likewise the name of the file, but as of version 11 it was still a regular file whose contents were coöperatively maintained by the system utility programs.

AIX does not export a human-readable text table that programs have to parse, and there is no equivalent file.  The BSDs, similarly, have fully-fledged system calls, `getfsstat()` on FreeBSD and OpenBSD, for programs to obtain the mount table from the kernel in machine-readable form without marshalling it through a human-readable intermediate form.

## Further reading

- Zygmunt Krynicki (2019-03-16). *[\r in path confuses mount units](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12018)*.  #12018.  systemd issues.
- Zbigniew Jędrzejewski-Szmek (2019-04-04). *[[df] incorrect parsing of `/proc/self/mountinfo` with \r in mount path](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2019-04/msg00005.html)*.  #35137.  GNU coreutils bugs.
- [`/proc/mounts`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1-rc6/source/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#L631).  *Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt*.  Linux 5.1.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019-02-28). *[Re: what is the purpose of `fstab-decode`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=567071#59)*.  Bug #567071.  Debian bugs.
- [`getfsstat()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getfsstat).  *FreeBSD System Calls Manual*.  2016-12-27.

Comment: In complement with my comment in the question here is the `mtab(5)` from the old days: http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/5/mtab.

Comment: not only `/proc/mounts`, but `/proc/self/mounts` is itself a compatibility mechanism now; it's only showing a subset of the info available in `/proc/self/mountinfo`. The format of `/proc/self/mounts` is documented in `proc(5)` as identical to `fstab(5)`

Comment: though admittedly, fstab(5) only tells about spaces being replaced by octal escapes, while it's [spaces, tabs, newlines and backslashes](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc_namespace.c?id=12a54b150fb5b6c2f3da932dc0e665355f8a5a48#n85)

Comment: I know pseudo files and regular files, but what is a pseudo regular file?

Comment: @gerrit it's a regular file which has size 0 but still contains data ;-)

Comment: Linux /proc/self/{mounts,mountinfo} are also pollable, allowing programs to watch for changes. (Though it doesn't actually tell you what the changes are; you have to re-read the whole table.)

Comment: This is a very high quality answer.Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

According to `man mount`:

> The  programs  mount and umount traditionally maintained a list of currently mounted filesystems in the file /etc/mtab. This real mtab file is still supported, but on current Linux systems it is  better to make  it  a symlink to /proc/mounts instead, because a regular mtab file maintained in userspace cannot reliably work with namespaces, containers and other advanced Linux features.

On mounting without recording in `/etc/mtab`:

> -n, --no-mtab
>
> Mount without writing in /etc/mtab.  This is necessary for example when /etc is on a read-only filesystem.

Many more nuances are given in the manual page.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of JdeBP might be the most actual and useful, I can add something from my (a bit outdated) Linux Learning Prep Guide which also gives a view on how it is / was used before:

> The difference between `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/mounts` is that `/etc/mtab` is the user space administration kept by `mount`, and `/proc/mounts` is the information kept by the kernel. [source](https://lpic2.unix.nl/lpic2.203.1/)