# Should the use of /etc/mtab now be considered deprecated?

Tags: linux, proc, compatibility

I'm curious about the file or symlink `/etc/mtab`. I believe [this is a legacy mechanism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/514095/20140). On every modern linux I've used this is a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts` and if `mtab` were to be a regular file on a "normal" file system `/etc` there would be challenges in making software work with mount namespaces.

For a long time I'd presumed that one of two things were true.  Either:

- We're waiting for software referencing `/etc/mtab` to age out or be updated
- Other non-linux OS still use the same file name and the link is there for cross platform compliance

However both of these seem shaky ideas.  I can't find good reference to any modern OS keeping the same file name outside Linux.  And it seems to have lived for much too long to be simply a backward compatibility issue; far more significant changes seem to have come and gone in that same time.

So I'm left wondering if `/etc/mtab` is really just there for historic reasons.  Is it in any way officially deprecated?  Is there any solid **modern** reason [as of 2023] to keep it?

*I don't want to delete it from my system, but as a software developer I'd like to understand its usefulness and whether to avoid it.*

Comment: Inevitably someone has voted this is "opinion based" you'll note I'm looking for an official position not just your personal opinion.

Comment: As a software developer, what would you use it for? What's the issue it poses to you?

Comment: @Kusalananda you might interpret this whole question as exactly that. I don't know. I'm curious what would you still use it for and would those uses now be depreciated.

Comment: As far as other Unix-style systems are concerned, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/514095/86440) — basically, as you suggest, `/etc/mtab` isn’t relevant there. In any case the Linux `/etc/mtab` isn’t even compatible with [old Unix-style `mtab`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/5/mtab).

Comment: man mount *classic /etc/mtab is completely disabled at compile time by default*, man umount *deprecated /etc/mtab*, systemd NEWS *Any reference to /etc/mtab has been dropped from systemd. The file has been obsolete since a while*. However I get >200 results just grepping for etc/mtab in my usr/lib and usr/bin. So it'll be around for quite a while, I suppose. It's still the same file format and other than kernel taking over, not much else changed...

Comment: @Philip see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#DESCRIPTION and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/umount.8.html#OPTIONS for `mount` and `umount`.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I'm willing to say "c'mon, that's work you can do yourself!": That man page comes from  [upstream](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/mount.8.adoc), and a bit of `git log -S "The support for regular classic"` later, we see that commit b6cc121043854e1048d020bc1d73d932df89eb4b documented the deprecation in 2018. (not saying it, instead instead showing off how you can find such info yourself)

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's not lazyness. I always ask those citing references to post something a little more tangible than a man command because they suffer many of the same [problems as posting links to google searches](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5813/posting-a-link-to-a-google-search-could-most-certainly-be-considered-rude-by-ma) namely they age out and different people get different results.

Comment: 2016 mailing list discussion [kill mtab - lore.kernel.org](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20160407105400.jn66tldxy7s3rqyc@ws.net.home/t/#u) *btw, mount(8) supports /etc/mtab -> /proc/mounts symlink for 20
years...* :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should the use of /etc/mtab now be considered deprecated?

Depends on who you ask. If you ask the authors of mount on Linux, yes; [since 2018](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commit/b6cc121043854e1048d020bc1d73d932df89eb4b#diff-481e1b14247749837fd760ec168213f7194b84ef273aae3ebd2fcff29bc6aab1) it says

> … is completely disabled in compile time by default, because on current Linux systems it is better …

I think that's pretty strong a statement. Prior to that, /etc/mtab was "also supported", but it was considered better to not use it:

> This real mtab file is still supported, but on current Linux systems it is
> better to make it a symlink to…

That sentence was there since [2014](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commit/00d1cc1ddff5b4800e64ba5894584159e4c7dd59#diff-481e1b14247749837fd760ec168213f7194b84ef273aae3ebd2fcff29bc6aab1L234). Before that, it was only *recommended*:

> The mtab file is still supported, but it's recommended to use a symlink to …

In other words, yeah. This has been deprecated for nearly a decade. You shouldn't rely on it. Ignore.

The source of truth is /proc/mounts, if anything. (Listing mounts correctly, uniquely and unambigously gets a logically non-trivial problem considering Linux mount namespaces exist)

Comment: Showing that timeline is really helpful in understanding it's current status and understanding why it is still around despite its apparent age. 2019 is more recent than I'd imagined when I wrote the question. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilipCouling absolutely had the same feeling!

Comment: Yeah it should be a symlink, because the real mtab is better located on `/run`. I've had periodic issues with it being `/proc/mounts`. Sometimes `/proc/mounts` really is wrong. (Don't think you have this issue? You probably don't. `systemd` has some unfixed multipath bugs that only show up in edge cases.) The reason `/proc/mounts` can be wrong is it has the device path from when it was mounted, which isn't the on-disk device path when it was initially mounted from initrd.

Comment: @Joshua Interesting point about devices changing name and invalidating `/proc/mounts`. On balance `/proc/mounts` seems safer for much modern software because it safely tracks through namespaces and chroot. IE if it's not generated by the kernel there's a high risk it's wrong. But then I guess that creates a problem because the kernel is largely unaware of which device file its mounted. It understands device numbers instead

Answer (score 2):

I was going to add this as a comment but a better utility than `/etc/mtab`, which is deprecated, and even `/proc/mounts`, which is supported and useful, is

```
findmnt
```

It is not always there by default depending on the distro but is almost always in the repos. It gives the same information as `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/mounts` and has switches to parse the data and print out only what is needed or wanted or to just render it more legible. These can be found via its `man` page.